# How to create json object for mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm building json object which I want to insert to an already existing collection in mongoldb with data using `pymongo`. The data looks like this:

```
[
 {
    "title": "PyMongo",

    "publication_date": "2015-09-07 10:00:00",
    "tags": ["python", "mongodb", "nosql"],
    "author": {
        "name": "David",
        "author_info": {
        "$oid": "1870981708ddb1a352189e25w"
        },
    },
    "date": {
             "$date": 1484071215000 }, 
   }
]
```

I noticed author has objectid and date is a timestamp, how can I create values for `author_info` and `date` and insert into mongodb?

I have a function that builds the values like this:

```
def build_json(title, pubctndate,taglist,author):
    json_ob = \
    [ {
       "title": title,
       "publication_date": pubctndate,
       "tags": tablets,
       "author": {
         "name": author,
         "author_info": {
         "$oid": " "
        },
       },
      "date": {"$date": }, 
     }]

   return json_ob
```

which I intend to call this way `json.dumps(build_json(title, pubctndate,taglist,author))`

Please bear with me, I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: `"date": {"$date": }` This is invalid json. Where's the value of `"$date"`?

Comment: @MYGz that's exactly my question. I don't know how to create values for `date` and `author_info`. Are they automatically created by mongodb?